# Mongoid multiple has_one relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, has-one

I struggling to get these relationships to work.
I have the following class FlowContainer

```
class FlowContainer
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :production_flow, class_name: Flow
  has_one :test_flow, class_name: Flow
  has_one :design_flow, class_name: Flow
end
```

As you can see I want it to have 3 specific flows. And I setup the relationship in the Flow like this:

```
class Flow
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :flow_container
end
```

I don't think this is something special and should work in my opinion but when I try to assign a flow to one of the specific flows mentioned above I get this error message:

> NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `sub' for Flow:Class

I could also go for the inheritance setup for a generic flow and 3 sub class but for the moment I'm not in favor for that solution because I feel this should work.
If somebody could share his opinion on this matter, I would appreciate it.

Comment: can you post your controller code?\

Comment: set the `inverse_of` relationships

Comment: Shouldn't the class name be a string?  "Flow" instead of the constant Flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `class_name` must be pass as an `string`, try this:

```
has_one :test_flow, class_name: "Flow"
```